# VBA Code No Longer appears in Developer/VBA window of Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I have Windows 10 Enterprise, and Outlook 365.  Starting within the past 7 days the VBA code no longer displays. (The VBA Editor does open.)  I had 100+ individual subs stored in 6 different modules.  The modules are still present but contain no content.  I have ~75% of the code backed up that I could copy / paste back into the VBA editor, but the window will not allow me to do so.  Plus, the window will not allow me to type anything either.  When double-clicking a VBA module (or by right-clicking and selecting View Code), the code window does not appear. (See the attached image.)

VBA Window

[image: 1]

I've tried changing View in the VBA window to every View option available, hoping my problem was just a view setting.  Didn't work.

I checked to ensure the Microsoft VBA for Outlook Add-in was still present.  It is.

I checked that Macros are enabled in Trust Center/Macro Settings.  They are (Enable all macros).

Comment: If you export your modules is the code there as before in the exported file?

Comment: What about *Window>>Tile Horizontally* (for example)?

Comment: Does the code still work? @TimWilliams suggestions are both really good and if the code isn't corrupted, tiling or cascading the windows will likely fix the issue.

Comment: Many thanks for replies.  I exported a module and saved the exported file.  Navigated to the saved location.  The exported file is not there!!!  I did this twice;  same result.  Thinking it might be a hidden file, I clicked "show hidden files"....still not there!   I tried Windows>>Tile Horizontally, Windows>>Tile Vertically, and Windows>>Cascade.  The view doesn't change with any of those efforts!!  The code worked flawlessly for several years, so I assume if I could access the code it would still work.  Again, thanks for replies......this one has me stumped.

Comment: open the module as text file and double check if the code is there

Comment: maybe your otm file is corrupted. you may want to find it, rename it and regenerate a new file c.f. [Managing and distributing Outlook Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/deployment/manage-distribute-outlook-vba-project)

Comment: I opened file "VbaProject.otm" with NotePad.  There's a mixture of text and characters in the file.  See snippet below